# Select element works only once after function executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a registration form getting generated dynamically which I'm trying to manipulate. What I need is that when I select 'Retired' in the dropdown for 'Profession' the section below it saying 'Present Occupation/Job' should be hidden and shown when 'Active' is selected. Below is that code for that.

```
<div class="upme-field upme-edit upme-edit-show">
    <label class="upme-field-type" for="profession">
        <i class="upme-icon-briefcase"></i><span>Profession</span>
    </label>
    <div class="upme-field-value">
        <select class="upme-input" name="profession" id="profession" title="Profession">
            <option value="Active">Active</option>
            <option value="Retired">Retired</option></select><div class="upme-clear">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="upme-field upme-edit upme-edit-show">
   <label class="upme-field-type" for="present-job">
      <i class="upme-icon-briefcase"></i>
  </label>
  <div class="upme-field-value">
      <input type="text" class="upme-input" name="present-job" id="present-job" value="" title="Present Occupation / Job">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="upme-field upme-edit upme-edit-show">
   <label class="upme-field-type" for="previous-job">
      <i class="upme-icon-briefcase"></i>
  </label>
  <div class="upme-field-value">
      <input type="text" class="upme-input" name="previous-job" id="previous-job" value="" title="Previous Occupation / Job">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery for the above mentioned task is:

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'select[name=profession]', function() {
    var presentJobLabel = $('label[for=present-job]');
    if($(this).val('Retired')){
        $(presentJobLabel).parent().hide();
    }
    else{
        $(presentJobLabel).parent().show();
    }
});
```

Now, what happens is that upon page load, 'Active' is selected and when I change it to 'Retired' the function works fine. But I'm not able to change it back to 'Active' after that. The select dropdown just closes with 'Retired' remaining selected. Why does it happen so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: `$(this).val('Retired')` you are setting the value. You should be checking `$(this).val() === 'Retired'`

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'select[name=profession]', function () {
    var presentJobLabel = $('label[for=present-job]');
    if ($(this).val() == 'Retired') {
        $(presentJobLabel).parent().hide();
    } else {
        $(presentJobLabel).parent().show();
    }
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PGG2E/)</kbd>